# Audio not working in Wine on Debian 9

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, wine

Whenever I run a Windows application in Wine I get this error and subsequently no sound:

```
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} not registered 
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {bcde0395-e52f-467c-8e3d-c4579291692e} could be created for context 0x1 
err:dsound:get_mmdevenum CoCreateInstance failed: 80040154
```

I use Debian 9 64 bit with PulseAudio and LXDE. Testing sound in `winecfg` works. So far I've only installed 32 bit software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem adding Wine repository to apt sources.list file and installing Wine using the steps described in the [official Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian), instead of just doing `sudo apt install wine`. Probably I was missing some libraries.